# не корректно отображается outline в unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

я делаю киберказуальную игру в юнити по типу Shape shifting. в игре у игрока и врагов есть обводка которую я сделал с помощью ассета Quick Outline (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488). игрок может менять модельку выключая и включая их.

Проблема в том что если моделька будет изначально будет выключена а потом включена outline выглядит так:

[image: первая картинка]

а если она изначально включена то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему так происходит, я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается надо было у мешей опцию read/write поставить true